# in robotium how to handle multiple classes

Tags: java, junit, robotium

i am having the same problem 
i am using 3 classes(classA, ClassB , ClassC ), and solo_d class, in my ClassC i am having test and in ClassA and ClassB i am using solo.sleep only

```
public class ClassA extends Solo_d{
public void click_on_save(){
Log.v("Test" , "Test in classA");
solo.sleep(5000);                // getting error null pointer exception 
solo.clickOnText("Saved")
}}


public class ClassC extends Solo_d {
ClassA aa = new ClassA();
@Test
public void test001(){
Log.v("Test" , "Test Start ");
aa.click_on_save();
}}
```

and i am using ClassB same as classA and using in ClassC

in Solo_d class i have given proper Activity and solo definition its working fine individual and also working fine if i am using as ClassB extends Solo_d 
ClassA extends  ClassB
ClassC extends  ClassA
but if i do not want to extend ClassA in ClassB , ClassB in ClassC 
it will be difficult to know the sequence of the inheritance

but i am getting NullPointerException 
anybody can help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need to add constructor to class A and remove "extends Solo_d"

```
public class ClassA{

    static Solo solo;

    //contructor
    public ClassA(Solo _solo){
      solo = _solo
    }

    public void click_on_save(){
    Log.v("Test" , "Test in classA");
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.clickOnText("Saved");
    }
}
```

and in your ClassC:

```
public class ClassC extends Solo_d {

    @Test
    public void test001(){
    ClassA aa = new ClassA(solo);
    Log.v("Test" , "Test Start ");
    aa.click_on_save();
    }
}
```

You could create the same constructor in you ClassC and call it in your Solo_d class (for example, in your setUp() method)

```
public class ClassC {

    static Solo solo;
    public ClassC(Solo _solo){
        solo = _solo
    }
    ClassA aa = new ClassA(solo);
    @Test
    public void test001(){
    Log.v("Test" , "Test Start ");
    aa.click_on_save();
    }
}
```

It works for me, hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: i have added constructor to class A and removed "extends Solo_d" but its giving same NullPointerException on solo

Comment: @Brad Larson i know, that was not my answer but i need make my question more clear to VMaleev, as i am new in stack overflow so i was not getting option to edit question below VMaleen's answer

Comment: Could you share your Solo_d class in full here? Possibly, the reason is in it.

Comment: public class Solo_d extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "com.test.testActivity";
private static Class<?> launcherActivityClass;
static{
        try {
                launcherActivityClass =Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
      }

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Solo_d() {
        super(launcherActivityClass);
        } 
public Solo solo;
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    } 

}

Comment: If i am using Class 
public class ClassC{
static Solo solo;
public ClassC(Solo _solo) {
    solo = _solo;
} 
ClassA Gr = new ClassA(solo);  
@Test
public void test001() throws Exception {
    Log.v("Test" , "Test Start ");  
    Gr.click_on_save(); 
    Log.v("Test" , "Test end ");
} }
i am getting error Failed to launch test

Comment: I can not find where you call constructor for C class. Do you call it anywhere? If your Solo_d class does nothing except solo initialization, why can not you combine Solo_d and C classes? About "Failed to launch test": need full log exception to say what is it.

Comment: Please check my all classes in my classA i am having :- public class ClassA  {
 static Solo solo;
 public ClassA(Solo solo1){
  solo = solo1;
 }
 public void click_on_save() throws Exception {
  Log.v("VVM Test" , "Test in greeting class ");
  solo.sleep(5000);
  solo.clickOnText("Saved");
  solo.sleep(5000);
 }} and

Comment: In ClassC i am having :- public class ClassC  extends Solo_D {
 Solo_D sol = new Solo_D();
 ClassA Gr = new ClassA(solo);  
 @Test
 public void test001() throws Exception {
  Log.v("VVM Test" , "Test Start ");
  Gr.click_on_save(); 
  Log.v("VVM Test" , "Test end ");
 } }

Comment: in class Solo_D :- public class Solo_D extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
 private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "test.Activity";
 static Solo solo;
    public Solo_D() {
      super(launcherActivityClass);
    } 
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
     //super.setUp();
     solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
        }}    some part from Solo_D i have removed due to limitation of words

Comment: I will have more Classes like ClassA , ClassB, ClassD ....  for all these classes i need solo initialization so i have kept solo initialization in separate class Solo_D , and methods in all these classes will be used in one test that is in ClassC   .So i want to extend only ClassC to Solo_D and wants to use solo object in all other classes hope you can understand why i am using separate Solo_D class . if u have any other way/suggestion  to achieve this part u can tell me that also thanks for supporting me .

Comment: move the "ClassA Gr = new ClassA(solo);" into the test001().

Comment: thanks Vmaleev its working fine now, can u explain why it was not working by  initializing ClassA outside test001

Comment: I can not say why exactly it happens, but I guess that it depends on test lifecycle. Perhaps, as ClassC contains method with @Test, it is initialized before setUp() is called. So, the instance of the ClassA contains solo=null as it had not been initialized in Solo_d yet.